# Vertical scrollbar issue arround marquee with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, marquee

Please help me i am  facing a very small vertical scrollbar problem in Internet Explorer 8 with marquee tag.
here are details :
Problem snapshot is attached in this post please zoom to see the issue :[image]

Html and css code is :

```html
<div id="divMarq" style="font-family:tahoma,arial,helvetica; font-size:11px; color:red; MARGIN-TOP:0.5CM; font-weight:bold; clear:both; height:30;">
</div>
```

Javascript code is :

```js
function elcyMessage(data){
   execute = true;
   mesg = data[0];
   var val = data[1];
   var executionState = data[2];
   
   text = "<i><font size=2>"+mesg+"</font></i>";
   var createMarquee = "<MARQUEE DIRECTION=left BEHAVIOR=scroll SCROLLAMOUNT=10 SCROLLDELAY=200>" + text + "</MARQUEE>";
   if(executionState == "NoException"){
    if(val){
     if(document.getElementById("divMarq")!=null){
      DWRUtil.setValue("divMarq","");
     }
     if(document.getElementById("divMarq2")!=null){
      DWRUtil.setValue("divMarq2",createMarquee);
     }
    }else{
     if(document.getElementById("divMarq2")!=null){
      DWRUtil.setValue("divMarq2","");
     }
     if(document.getElementById("divMarq")!=null){
      DWRUtil.setValue("divMarq",createMarquee);
     }
    } 
   }else{
    if(document.getElementById("divMarq")!=null){
     DWRUtil.setValue("divMarq",createMarquee);
    } 
   }
  }
```

Also DocType Settings are:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
overflow: hidden;
```

To the marquee div's css. So somethuing like

```
<div id="divMarq" style="font-family:tahoma,arial,helvetica; font-size:11px; color:red; MARGIN-TOP:0.5CM; font-weight:bold; clear:both; height:30; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

This is caused by the fixed height of the div being slightly less than the line height of the text.

**Alternatives**
I try to provide an alternative to css questions as you can do most things more than one way.

You could also :

- Increase the height of the div.
- Remove the height entirely unless it is needed for the javascript so the div simply auto sizes to the content.

Comment: Thanks line-height worked. Overflow:hidden did not worked.